# ODBC escape user input without using prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, db2, odbc, prepared-statement

How do I escape or sanitize user input before sending it to a function that performs a database lookup (among other things)? I have no access to this function and it DOES NOT use prepared statements.

I'm using ODBC and DB2.

Detailed description below:

I have a text area that accepts a list of emails either comma separated or whitespace separated or both. My javascript will break up the text area string into an array (by replacing commas into spaces and then splitting the string by whitespace) and send it to the server to be processed.

In my php, I take each array index (an email) and send it to a function which does an email lookup. The function will verify the email by performing a database lookup via odbc drivers and is NOT written as a prepared statement. The function does other stuff other than the lookup so I cannot simply rewrite it. I have no access to this function and cannot edit it.

Comment: No idea about DB2 but I've hit this wall working with Access. I don't know who to blame (PHP or ODBC) but the PHP ODBC extension does not seem to have a escape function at all. And prepared statements depend entirely on the driver.

Comment: It's been suggested to me to use htmlentities, but upon research, people have said to not use htmlentities when INSERTING. Since I am not inserting and only doing a select, using htmlentities might be a possible solution. There should be no email record that is html entitized.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the relationship between SQL and HTML :-?

Comment: I'm still fairly green to the world of SQL and webdev. From my understanding, htmlentities will convert a string's applicable characters which should help protect against attacks and injection.

Comment: HTML entities (among other things) allow to escape characters that have a special meaning in HTML (such as `<` or `&`). You use them for HTML, not for SQL (which would be like using a helmet to protect against flu ;-)

Comment: What about a possible workaround where I limit the characters that can be use in the textarea to that of allowed characters for email addresses? (Upon quick research, seems like this wouldn't help)

Or what about using some regular expression to validate the string is in the form of an email address?

Comment: I recommend you read the Wikipedia article about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as starting point.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. I was just looking for a quick solution to this problem. I'll probably end up requesting to have the function rewritten to use a prepared statement. I just don't want to have the conversation on why I can't just use htmlentities like I was suggested to use. My team has little to no experience with prepared statements and I actually introduced them to it on my last project.

Comment: Create a second function that does accept a prepared statement and use it for the validation.